# Blazor server authorized downstream API call with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, blazor, asp.net-identity, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

I’m trying to use `Microsoft.Identity.Web` to call an API from my .NET 6 Blazor server app. I can successfully login to authorized pages in my Blazor app but when I try to make an API call using `CallWebApiForUserAsync` I get an inner exception of “**No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call**”.

The couple of posts here on Stack Overflow and the MS documentation look to me like I have it configured correctly. What am I missing?

appsettings.json:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://hivercom.b2clogin.com/XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
    "Instance": "https://XXXXXX.b2clogin.com",
    "TenantId": "XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Domain": "XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PasswordReset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_EditProfile",
    "ClientSecret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "HiverAPI": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:7075",
    "Scopes": "https://XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com/XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX/all"
  },
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using BlazorB2C.Data;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.InMemory;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd")
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "https://XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com/XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX/all" })
    .AddDownstreamWebApi("HiverService", builder.Configuration.GetSection("HiverAPI"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
              .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
              .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = context =>
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
        context.HandleResponse();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Level.razor:

```
@page "/level"
@using Microsoft.Identity.Web

@inject IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory
@inject Microsoft.Identity.Web.ITokenAcquisition TokenAcquisitionService
@inject Microsoft.Identity.Web.IDownstreamWebApi DownstreamWebApi
@inject MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler ConsentHandler

@attribute [Authorize]
@attribute [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "HiverAPI:Scopes")]

<PageTitle>Level</PageTitle>

<a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut">Log out</a>

<h3>Level</h3>

@code {
    private const string ServiceName = "HiverService";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        try
        {
        error >> string token = await TokenAcquisitionService.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "https://XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com/XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX/all" });

        error >> var value = await DownstreamWebApi.CallWebApiForUserAsync(
                ServiceName,
                options =>
                {
                    options.RelativePath = $"HiverUser";
                });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.Message;

            ConsentHandler.HandleException(ex);
        }

        try
        {
        error >> await DownstreamWebApi.CallWebApiForUserAsync(
                ServiceName,
                options =>
                {
                    options.HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Put;
                    options.RelativePath = $"HiverUser/0fd30e94-a116-4ef0-b222-4125546b8561";
                });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.Message;

            ConsentHandler.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }    
}
```

Azure configuration for client app:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Azure configuration for API

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CallWebApiForAppAsync` uses the on-behalf flow, which is not available for Azure AD B2C.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/b2c-limitations

> You cannot use ITokenAcquisition.GetTokenForAppAsync or IDownstreamApi.CallWebApiForAppAsync in Azure AD B2C web apps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens

As an alternative, you can request access tokens for downstream APIs(Hiver.API in your case) using `GetAccessTokenForUserAsync`. The resulting access token can be used to call the API. You'll need to use a standard `HttpClient` instead of `IDownstreamWebApi`. Full example can be found here:

- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-server/blob/main/WebApp-your-API/B2C/README-Incremental.md

Relevant code from Github:

```cs
private async Task PrepareAuthenticatedClient()
{
    var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { _TodoListScope });
    Debug.WriteLine($"access token-{accessToken}");
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```