How to pass Azure B2C access tokens in Blazor Server
I have been working for like few days on trying to figure out a way to fetch the access token in blazor server application, but so far it didnt worked out.
this is what i have in program.cs
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, Constants.AzureAdB2C);
builder.Services.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();`

also when i try to fetch the token using ITokenAcquisition in razor page, i see another error although user is already signed in:
MSAL.NetCore.4.60.3.0.MsalUiRequiredException:
ErrorCode: user_null
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.
also another problem is that i have to pass the scope for, my enterprise portal which i couldn't figure how to do in Blazor server, although below code i can see for Blazor WASM:
  builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
  { 
builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C",
    options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("enterpriseportalscopeurl");
     options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect"; });

i also tried this
[Inject]
public ITokenAcquisition TokenAcquisitionService { get; set; }`

string token = await TokenAcquisitionService.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync("scopeurl", authenticationScheme: "OpenIdConnect")

but it resulted in error: below is some exception related to that
Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition: Error: False MSAL 4.60.3.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.2 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044 [2024-05-09 14:20:01Z - 61481e5d-6a0d-47c8-854b-744efd5bd249] Exception type: Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException
, ErrorCode: user_null
HTTP StatusCode 0
CorrelationId 61481e5d-6a0d-47c8-854b-744efd5bd249
To see full exception details, enable PII Logging. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-logging
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<<RunAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Utils.StopwatchService.MeasureCodeBlockAsync(Func`1 codeBlock)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException' in Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition: Information: [MsIdWeb] An error occured during token acquisition: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call. 

MSAL.NetCore.4.60.3.0.MsalUiRequiredException:
    ErrorCode: user_null
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call. 
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<<RunAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Utils.StopwatchService.MeasureCodeBlockAsync(Func`1 codeBlock)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ClientApplicationBaseExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenSilentParameters silentParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForWebAppWithAccountFromCacheAsync(IConfidentialClientApplication application, ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, IEnumerable`1 scopes, String tenantId, MergedOptions mergedOptions, String userFlow, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(IEnumerable`1 scopes, String authenticationScheme, String tenantId, String userFlow, ClaimsPrincipal user, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions)
    StatusCode: 0 
    ResponseBody:  
    Headers: 
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException' in Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

It will be a great help if anyone already solved this problem.
I tried with token acquisition and it throw the msal ui exception.
Also i tried catching token during app load, but it works only when app is build, if i leave my app open, it doesn't go to builder code.`

Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73585961/blazor-server-authorized-downstream-api-call-with-azure-ad-b2c?rq=2

@Sridevi thank you for sharing the link, although the below code doesnt work anymore with .net8
var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { _TodoListScope });
it gives msal ui exception

Please include the msal ui exception that you are currently getting by editing your question

@Sridevi updated the question with exception in detail
